# How can in insert tuple data with python in postgres

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have the header dict as this

```
header= {
'catA' : {
'name': 'user_name',
'age':'user_age'
},
'catB' : {
'name': 'person_name',
'age': 'person_age'
}
}
```

The postgres table is flat with all columns from header like this

`user_name , user_age, person_name, person_age`

The data which i want to insert looks like this, one row per row in DB

data = `[('user_name', 'john'), ('user_age', '23'), ('person_name', 'rupan') . . . ]`

what is best way to insert

I want something like this

`query = "INSERT INTO mytable (header.cols) VALUES (data)"`

Also i want to esacpe the data so that no malacious data goes in database

Comment: It would be nice to add information about PostgreSQL driver you use. Is it ODBC, psycopg, pg8000? If you use Jython you can also use JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape parameters but this not good idea. It is better to use prepared statement. Such statements are much easier do database to parse and use. See at pyodbc explanation: http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted#Parameters

There is code that uses such prepared statement:

```
data = [
    ('user_name', "Adam 'Adi' Bobek"), ('user_age', 23), ('person_name', "Jurek 'Jerry' Jimowski") ,('person_age', 28),
    ]
data = dict(data)
cols = ",".join(data.keys())
qmarks = ','.join(['?' for s in data.keys()])
values = [v for v in data.values()]
insert_statement = "INSERT INTO users (%s) VALUES (%s);" % (cols, qmarks)

import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect('DSN=pglocal')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(insert_statement, values)
connection.commit()
```

Other PostgreSQL/database drivers (psycopg, JDBC) can use similar techniques. This was tested with `pyodbc` and `odbc` (part of PyWin32 package that is also part of ActiveState Python distribution).

EDIT:

There is example of prepared with `psycopg2`, read: http://www.psycopg.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries to find more:

```
import psycopg2
....
connect_string = 'dbname=test host=localhost port=5493 user=postgres password=postgres'
connection = psycopg2.connect(connect_string)
cursor = connection.cursor()
psycopg_marks  = ','.join(['%s' for s in data.keys()])
insert_statement = "INSERT INTO users (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (cols, psycopg_marks)
cursor.execute(insert_statement, values)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: I tried your code and it gave me this error `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...ct_area) VALUES (nextval('my_id_seq'), ?,?,?,?,?,?...`

Comment: `pscopg2` is similar, but use `%s` instead of `?` used by ODBC or JDBC. See my updated answer and read: http://www.psycopg.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries , especially "The problem with the query parameters"

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
>>> data = [('user_name', 'john'), ('user_age', '23'), ('person_name', 'rupan') ,('person_age',28)]
>>> data = dict(data)
>>> cols = ",".join(data.keys())
>>> values = ",".join("'"+ v + "'" if type(v) is str else str(v) for v in data.values())
>>> query = "INSERT INTO mytable (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (cols,values)
>>> query
"INSERT INTO mytable (person_name,user_name,user_age,person_age) VALUES ('rupan','john','23',28)"
```

Comment: that looks correct but my values conatin all sort of characters like `'";{}<>\` that is causing error. how can i escape thise before inserting